# Using Both +5V GPIO Pins for More Current?

Tags: gpio, power

According to this website: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin2_5v_power#

The +5V GPIO pins can push up to 1.5A of current, and are attached directly to the Pi's power supply.

My question is, if I use both +5V pins and connect them in parallel (using diodes just in case), could I draw up to 3A assuming the main power supply is sufficient?

Comment: RPi makes for an expensive fuse ... i suggest that you use a separate power supply for your project

Comment: @jsotola How would I ensure a common ground reference between a Pi and an externally powered peripheral? Would I connect the ground of the peripheral to the Pi's ground (in addition to the ground of the power supply, duh)? Would it be sufficient if the power supply for the Pi and the peripheral shared a ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 5V pins are already connected (and also to the on-board 5V rail - which, depending on model, is NOT "attached directly to the Pi's power supply").

Using both will make NO difference. (Strictly there will be a minor reduction in resistance, but as this is negligible it would be impossible to measure.)

Note the pins do not **push** anything! The current drawn will be dependent on load.

No you cannot draw 3A. Depending on Pi model current is limited by polyfuse, and some is needed to run the Pi itself and attached peripherals. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Attempting to draw heavy currents is likely to overload the thin copper traces on the board.

Comment: Never set this as the answer -- sorry about that. Just did.